# In Azure Data Factory how do I specify an SQL filter to select documents one day old

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb

In Azure Data Factory I have a copy activity. I have as a source a Cosmos NoSQL database. I am trying to select from the source files that are one day old using an SQL filter:

```
@concat('SELECT * FROM c where c.createdDate>"',subtractFromTime(utcNow(),1,'Day'),'"')
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxBwu.png)

However there are no documents selected

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the following sample data in cosmos db

```json
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Rakesh",
        "createdDate": "2023-04-27T11:31:16.5438142Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Laddu",
        "createdDate": "2023-04-25T11:31:16.5438142Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Chinna",
        "createdDate": "2023-04-28T11:31:16.5438142Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Virat",
        "createdDate": "2023-04-20T11:31:16.5438142Z"
    }
]
```

When I used the same query as yours, you can see I am able to get the desired result in the preview of the source.

[image]

Make sure your data is correct as per the query. If still it results same, try with **String interpolation** in the query like below.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM c
where c.createdDate>"@{subtractFromTime(utcNow(),1,'Day')}"
```